# Windows 11 using Task Scheduler to change the Windows light/dark theme EXACTLY like how Settings would do it

Tags: windows, windows-11, taskbar, scheduled-tasks, themes

Since Windows 11 doesn't have the light/dark theme depending on time of day, I decided to implement one through Task Scheduler. Basically at certain times, I'd change the binary values of

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize\SystemUsesLightTheme
```

and

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize\AppsUseLightTheme
```

to 1 or 0. The issue is that this doesn't do 2 things

1. Gradually shift the colors
2. Change the taskbar colors (this one's a bit tricky - I noticed if I restart Windows Explorer, the taskbar changes. I don't want to do that though since that messes with open files and slows down the computer).

I'm not sure how this is implemented within settings so I wanted to see if there's a better way of doing this. I'd also be open to directly triggering the setting automatically. I'm not sure if there's a file or something associated with it that I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing when I was trying to make a normally working auto theme change via Task Scheduler. Including trying to auto on/off system transparency during the theme swap and running a separate .theme config file through Task Scheduler, but both ways didn't give the desired result.
But I found two alternative ways how to fix this problem:

## First method — Luna

[image: Luna settings]

The main advantage of this program is that it uses the Task Scheduler for theme changing, so it does not require running in the background!
The only thing is that to make it work correctly, you need to select the option "Based on .theme file" in the "Let the app change Windows appearance" and select its location, as in the picture above.

### Creating a .theme file

[image: Theme settings window]

In order to create a .theme configuration, you have to go to Persoanalization -> Themes in the settings, set the theme and click on Save. This operation has to be done twice for dark and white theme respectively. The customized themes are saved in this path: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`

#### Download page: [Github](https://github.com/adrianmteo/Luna)

## Second method — AutoDarkMode

[image: Picture: AutoDarkMode UI]

It is similar to Lune, except that it has much more functionality, does not require any .theme configuration files for correct work but always running in the background.

#### Download page: [MS Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/auto-dark-mode/XP8JK4HZBVF435) / [Github](https://github.com/AutoDarkMode/Windows-Auto-Night-Mode)